How does experience joy without clinging?
Buddhist teachings say one must restrain the senses and cultivate equanimity but I struggle to find a balance between doing that and finding joy in life etc.  Do I just notice joy arising and let go?

The Joy in Buddhism is different to the joy we normally refer in this world.
Normally the joy in the world is always caused by a thing in this world (eg: partner, car, degree, children, drugs, games, thinking about someone or some event,.....). All of these are clung to something.
So the short answer to your question is it cannot be done. As all the joys (what we refer in normal life) are always attached with something.
But the joy or the enlightenment in Buddhism has nothing to do with anything. It can exist without anything. That's why its important and that's why enlightenment is the cure to everything.
To get there we need to understand clearly (realize by our own minds) the basic of Buddhism. When someone realizes that the things (physical/mental) in external world is not behave as we want those to be. They also realize its meaningless to attach to somethings or run after things in this world. Also they will realize that attachment is always brings you unexpected results, as nothing in this world behaves the way we want those to be.
With that understanding the mind goes to some undependable state where it can exists without any support. You can refer to this state as joy in this context.

The joy that you are looking for is outside scope of buddhas teaching.
It is called sensual joy. delighting in 6 Sense object.
The real joy in buddhas teaching are two kind.
Joy of seclusion.
you understanding the cost of  'sensual joy'.you understand techniques to restrain from such joy. Then you feel relieved from bondage of craving sensual joy. and this relief is joyful. as if you are carrying a heavy load and you feel joyful if  put it down.
Joy of samadhi.
When you enter  into samadhi deeper than before. You first time see the true nature of your being. that nature is joyful.
